# Как рассчитать разницу во временных промежутках в процентом соотношении?

Tags: c#

Возникла ситуация: есть два массива на 10K и 100K элементов, над которыми используется один и тот же алгоритм сортировки. Во время сортировки для каждого массива, измеряется временной промежуток, который запоминает, сколько занимает сам процесс сортировки (код ниже). Есть необходимость рассчитать, на сколько процентов увеличилось время сортировки при изменении количества элементов массива. При написании кода, сталкиваюсь с вопросом: как правильно преобразовывать тип TimeSpan в double для подсчёта процентов и правильная ли эта мысль для решения данной задачи?

```
Stopwatch stopWatchForArray10k = new Stopwatch();
stopWatchForArray10k.Start();
InsertionSort(array10k);  // sorting an array1
stopWatchForArray10k.Stop();
TimeSpan timeSpanForArray10k = stopWatchForArray10k.Elapsed;

Stopwatch stopWatchForArray100k = new Stopwatch();
stopWatchForArray100k.Start();
InsertionSort(array100k);  // sorting an array2
stopWatchForArray100k.Stop();
TimeSpan timeSpanForArray100k = stopWatchForArray100k.Elapsed;


// Here there should be a calculation of how many percent the sorting 
// time has increased when the number of elements changes relative to the original number
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.totalmilliseconds?view=net-7.0

Comment: вообще зависит от вашего вопроса. Если вопрос в том, правильно ли вы измеряете производительность алгоритма - то не правильно, для этого есть либы типа benchmark .net. Если вопрос просто в том, как timespan в число переделать - глядите ссылку выше

Comment: Такая идея кода для измерения производительности алгоритма была дана преподавателем, поэтому менять её у меня пока нет необходимости, пусть даже и с осознанием, что расчёт такого кода может быть и не точным. Если другими словами, нужно рассчитать, на сколько увеличилось время для сортировки массива побольше, к времени сортировки массива поменьше, но в процентом соотношении. Код уже начинал писать, но вставал в ступор, т.к. не мог преобразовать тип TimeSpan в double, а пока это единственной путь, который я находил. Однако, ту ссылку, которую вы указали - это прям то, что надо. Спасибо большое!

Comment: @tym32167 Тегну вас, чтоб благодарность вам за подсказку не пролетела мимо. Далее я смогу найти решение самостоятельно, более вопрос не актуальный. Ещё раз спасибо

Comment: на здоровье, рад что помогло!

Comment: Можно проще `var milliseconds = stopWatchForArray10k.ElapsedMilliseconds;`

Comment: @aepot Спасибо! Мне понравилось данное решение =)